# attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0 ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2

I got a problem with Ubuntu 18.04. It has worked fine all the time, until I had to change the ventilation fan of the desktop. Since I changed the fan, and used spray duster on the CPU and the other parts of the  mother board, I get the following message at start-up which stops the system:

> attempt to read or write outside of disk hd0 ubuntu
>
> press any key to continue....

There is no chance to do any of the maneuvers that are described in other similar posts here on StackExchange, and therefore I cannot really do anything with it. However, if I restart again and again, at a certain stage, this warning does not appear and the system boots normally.

Is there some way to work around this occasionally appearing problem, or should I just continue as it is, and restart and restart over and over again till it works?

***UPDATE #1*** after corrections by heynnema.

All disks converted to GPT table. Reinstalled Ubuntu 18.10, but it doesn't start. All I get is the startup animation of the Ubuntu dots that flash from left to right, without any color in the background or anything happening. Inserting snapshot:

[image]

Another restart brings the regular Ubuntu background forth, but as the previous case, it just flashes its process lights from left to right. Nothing happens, the system does not start. What can I do? Should I go over to another table structure?

**UPDATE #2:** Updated the BIOS to most recent version. Tried to reinstall Ubuntu by erasing the disk and use LVM set up. Installation stopped when entering the LVM menu to make a boot table. Nothing happens, no buttons work. Before LIVD CD starts fully, it shows a dark screen with white text:

> APEI cannot start mem [342423e4dxxx..] or something

the Ubuntu Trial starts then on Live CD and when trying to format the boot drive from LIVE CD In Gparted, the option to format are hidden and cannot be used.
Entering Install setup and then at Install options selecting again "Erase Disk and install Ubuntu", it now says:

> The computer has not detected operating systems

Skipping LVM

Installation runs ahead.

Installation failed again. Same screen as depicted above in the image.

Comment: Use a liveCD to run `fsck` on the filesystem to correct it!

Comment: This is only a suggestion, but have your power supply checked.  I was experiencing the same errors and my power supply was bad.  It was also giving me issues when I would go to play 3d games that would ramp up the fan on my video card and my system would turn right off without warning.  But the boots were showing the same errors and I had to reboot several times.  Bad power supplies can cause unpredictable errors and problems.

Comment: I just changed the power supply a year ago

Comment: I did turn off the computer indeed. All appeared OK, hardware wise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen complaints of this type of error quite frequently. I've researched all of the various answers, and they're all over the place, with no particular one making much real sense. So I figure that I'll take a crack at it myself :-)

First thing to do is check the filesystem, like so...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Next, I want to take a look at how your hard disk is put together. Edit your question to include a screenshot of `gparted` when looking at your boot disk.

Also show me `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo blkid` and `free -h` and `swapon` and `cat /etc/fstab` and `ls -al /boot`. I know that's a lot of stuff to do, but we have to start somewhere. Copy/paste the output into an edit of your question, **please don't use the comments, or use screenshots**. Use the {} icon to help format the text if need be.

Also show me `systemctl status ureadahead`, and `grep -i ureadahead /var/log/syslog*`.

**Especially because this problem is somewhat intermittent, please understand that this troubleshooting and repair may take some time, so be very patient.**

**Update #1:**

**Although I haven't seen all of the information that I've requested, I've seen enough to have some conclusions.**

- all four 1TB disks (sda/b/c/d) are formatted with MBR partition tables. They should be GPT partition tables.
- sda2 "does not start on physical sector boundary".
- ureadahead is bombing `/var/log/syslog` and should be disabled in 18.xx.
- there's a possibility that some kind of ramdisk software is enabled, as I see many `/dev/ramX` in `sudo fdisk -l`. If so, this should be disabled.

What to do?

- boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and run `memtest` for one complete pass
- backup ALL of your disks
- make sure that your computer is set to `UEFI` mode in the BIOS
- install GPT partition tables on all 4 disks (**this will wipe these disks**)
- re-create ext4 partitions on sdb/c/d
- re-install Ubuntu on sda
- it looks like you have a 48G swap... that's insane... unless you're hibernating, and then the size needs to be large... make a much smaller swap
- re-run `sudo fdisk -l` and confirm that all partitions are aligned
- disable ureadahead

  - `sudo systemctl stop ureadahead`
  - `sudo systemctl disable ureadahead`
- do not install any ramdisk software, if you had previously
- restore your data

Comment: @user287546 thanks for the info... but as I requested in my answer, please **don't** use the comments to show me the output of the commands. Copy/paste the **complete** output, including the commands that you typed, as an edit to your question. Thanks! Also... fsck has to be done from a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB.

Comment: @user287546 although I certainly appreciate your efforts at getting the information to me, you're not following my instructions. Please do NOT post the command output to the comments. Rather copy/paste the ENTIRE command output, including the command itself, as an edit to your original question. Please delete the comments that show command output, and redo the entire chain. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, I did now what you said

Comment: I cannot paste grep -i ureadahead /var/log/syslog* ,the output in terminal is infinite. Many of the other outputs have been deleted auomatically even though I inserted them as you said...

Comment: None of the outputs were possible to paste in the original message, they are deleted

Comment: @user287546 although I haven't seen all of the information that I requested, I've made an Update #1 to my answer. There's a lot of work involved to straighten out the problems.

Comment: That is really a lot of work. I haven't had this problem ever before, neither on Ubuntu 18.04 before the fan change, or with Ubuntu 16.04, 14.04. I can assume that all those wrong variables you found must have either appeared after the swap of the fan, or they are not the cause. However, I have seen others posting this same message.  Can it be something with a Ubuntu 18.04 update? Thanks, I will try to make your changes

Comment: @user287546 Yes, it is a lot of work. But the system wasn't configured for optimum operation in the first place. You've got a lot of expense hardware, and you should be able to get the most out of it. Swapping the fan, or Ubuntu 18.xx, has nothing to do with your current problem(s).

Comment: @user287546 did some/all of my answer make sense to you? Will you be implementing some/all of it? Please keep me posted as to your status, ok?

Comment: See update above. Thanks

Comment: What? I'm so sorry to hear this news. How did you loose all your data? Didn't you backup your disks as I said in my procedure? sda is still MBR instead of GPT. There's no partition alignment problem. I'll bet there's no boot problem, although the disk still should be GPT. sdb/c look good as GPT. sdd appears in an unknown state. If you did a fresh install of 18.04 then ureadhead probably won't be active, that's good. Is there anything I can do to help you?

Comment: Although you may not wish to hear it, but since the condition of your machine is so bad right now, you might as well: backup sda data, install a GPT partition table on sda (this will wipe the disk), and reinstall Ubuntu again. At least your machine will be in better configuration, and you won't have any boot problems.

Comment: Did you make sure to check that your BIOS was set to UEFI mode?

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. There appears to be no boot problem any longer, so that helped indeed. About the loss of data, don't worry. About the sda, it should be in GPT? If it isn't, I have to reinstall 18.10 indeed again. Can you confirm that sda and sdd need to be in GPT?  The BIOS does not say anywhere if it is in UEFI mode. But boot appears OK, so I take it is.Thanks

Comment: @user287546 Correct, after backing up any sda data, installing a GPT partition table (will wipe the disk), you'll need to reinstall 18.10. Sorry. But to make sure that you don't have the boot problem again, it's important. **It's also important to recheck your BIOS first for UEFI. It might say "Legacy" now... or something like that... and it's important to change it to UEFI before you go through the whole process above**. sdd should be GPT also.

Comment: No problem at all, don't worry. <Seems I dont have UEFI. i talked to support. whaT table should i use?

Comment: GPT partition table on all 4 disks. Only sda and sdd are missing it now.

Comment: Hi – heynnema , seems there is a problem. THe ASUS motherboard, OR Ubuntu 18.10 does not like the GPT table on boot  disk. See update on my post.

Comment: @user287546 What kind of video card do you have? Try this... get to the GRUB menu, make sure the correct boot line is selected, hit the "e" key to edit the boot instructions, find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x to continue the boot. See if it gets further.

Comment: @user287546 Also, check the ASUS web site for a BIOS update. How old is the ASUS MB?

Comment: 5 years old Hyenema

Comment: @user287546 did nomodeset work? Is your BIOS current?

Comment: BIOS not updated. Nomodeset not tested. How do I get to the GRUB menu when the Ubuntu does not start?

Comment: @user287546 hold down SHIFT or ESC key at boot time. Was there a newer ASUS BIOS for your MB?

Comment: Waiting for upport to confirm on  BIOS update. Meanhile, I let the computer "stall" in the failed startup, and after sometime I found it in a different state, the background is gone, and I can only see command line startup with OK s and FAILED: "Starting to update UTMP about System Boot/Shutdown... FAILED. FAILE to start Network name resolution, failed to start network time sync, ......starting show plymouth boot screen s-up.down.ion 701

Comment: tried NOMODESET, was able to edit. Ubuntu seems frozen in a purple screen, no text, no logos, no nothing

Comment: @user287546 try `nomodeset`. You didn't say what video card you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91090/discussion-between-user287546-and-heynnema).

Comment: @user287546 What media did you install Ubuntu from? DVD? USB? When you installed Ubuntu, did you select "Use entire disk for Ubuntu"?

Comment: can you have a look at the second update in the original post? Thanks

Comment: @user287546 you're certainly having a lot of problems, huh? Did you ever do the first step of my procedure... memtest? If not, then that is the next priority. Boot to the Live DVD and choose memtest from the GRUB menu. Let's eliminate a memory problem. Make sure that you get one complete pass of the test... which in your case... since you have a lot of memory... could take a few hours. Report back.

Comment: @user287546 status update please.

Comment: sorry for answer late, but the Mem test is still running after 64 hours. It is  50 GB of memory + 24 CPU's cache. I take it will take a week or so?

Comment: @user287546 wow, that IS taking a long time... but if you haven't already cancelled it, let it run so we can truly say that memory is not a factor in all of your problems. Report back later.

Comment: @user287546 one other thing to do is check that the Ubuntu .iso image that you downloaded is ok. Go back to the download page and download one of the "sums" file, like md5sums. Then in `terminal` do `md5sum filename.iso` and compare that result with the content of the "sums" file, to verify the download was good.

Comment: OK thanks! Got this: /Downloads$ md5sum ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso 
d40aa9b8043849ecd888e85eade072db  ubuntu-18.10-desktop-amd64.iso - no sums file output

Comment: @user287546 now that you've got the md5sum for your .iso download, view the contents of the md5sums file, and compare your value with the stated value and make sure they match. If they don't, you've got a bad download. Make sure your md5sums file is for the same version as your .iso.

Comment: @ heynnema there is no md5sums file, only that output in the terminal I copied and pasted above

Comment: @user287546 go back to my comment from 2 hours ago... you have to download the md5sums file from probably the same place that you got the .iso file... http://releases.ubuntu.com/

Comment: I found the problem. The system did not start-up with one of the HD's being in another table format than GPT, although it was not a boot disk. I removed it, and now I have only GPT drives connected, and it has booted successfully 5 times in a row.

Comment: @user287546 Great news! Since my answer was spot on, please remember to accept it for me. Thanks!

Comment: I remember your wrote this in the chat session yes. What should I do to grant you acceptance credits here?

Comment: @user287546 Just click the little grey checkmark icon found just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91299/discussion-between-user287546-and-heynnema).

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a problem with your Grub installation.
Maybe a badly written file during a hard shutdown (i.e. turning PC off without a real shutdown).

You can try to force rewriting all grub files by reinstalling all Grub packages.
Don't remove them and reinstall them. If there is a problem while packages are uninstalled you may not be able to reboot again:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep grub)
sudo update-grub
```

The command "dpkg -l | awk '{ print $2 }' | grep grub" lists your grub related packages. For exemple (on my system):

```
grub-common
grub-efi-amd64
grub-efi-amd64-bin
grub-efi-amd64-signed
grub-legacy-ec2
grub2-common
```

Comment: @user287546 don't follow two different answers at the same time. It'll really make a mess of things. If you're going to follow my answer, then don't do this now.

Answer (score 1):

I just dug out of one of these problems myself with 5.0.0.27. Running fsck came out with no errors.

I finally booted from a flashdrive, moved /boot/grub/grub.cfg to a backup file and then copied the backup file back to the original name. Did the same thing with /boot/init... file, and /boot/vmlinuz... file.
Now my system boots!

My system is installed on a single 4TB partition and I think one of those files was out of reach for grub. Doing the move and copy seems to have put them back where grub can now read them.

I stumbled on this approach when I tried to 'cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg' from within grub and I got the same error about reading outside of hd0. When I booted from the flashdrive I had no problem mounting the /dev/sda2 partition and reading the file. Therefore I knew the file was still intact. That lead me to the thought that grub simply can't handle a 4TB drive if the boot files are "too far away". Maybe for me it's time to make /boot be a separate smaller partition!