# What will happen if we put the ubuntu installed disk from lenovo into dell?

Tags: boot, ssd, bootloader, ubuntu-core

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on my samsung ssd which was in lenovo thinkpad yoga 4th gen. 
Now I've changed my laptop and I remove ssd from Lenovo and pit it into dell latitude e5470 6th gen. Laptop. 
Now, booting problems occurs here after loading there displays a black screen on top of which `GNU GRUB version 2.02`  and

grub > _

What will be the solution? 
I changed the boot order also and also set it to legacy. I've tried doing all these.

Comment: Was the original installation UEFI or legacy?

Comment: It might be uefi

Comment: What if it was installed legacy mode? As I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a grub rescue shell like

```
grub>
```

That means Grub can't find some information needed to boot. Could be its configuration file *grub.cfg*, the folder containing Grub's modules, etc. usually because the partition set up has changed. There are a few commands you can use to see what the problem is:

```
ls
```

will show the partitions in your system. You should decide which one contains the folder /boot/grub (usually the one on which Ubuntu is installed. You can check what is in each partition issuing something like, for example

```
ls (hd0,2)/
```

to check partition 2 on disk 0

Once you found the drive containing Ubuntu,

```
set prefix=(hd0,2)/boot/grub
```

assuming your system is in (hd0,2). If not, change accordingly. Then,

```
insmod normal
```

If there are no errors, the system should boot with

```
normal
```

Let me know if the laptop doesn't boot. In that case you have to tell grub where the kernel and the initrd.img are located.

Once the computer boots. **First thing** you must do

```
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

again assuming your installation is in disk hd0. For disk hd1 is sdb, etc

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/
http://www.linuxandubuntu.com/home/ways-to-rescue-or-recover-grub-menu

Comment: There are two folders in (hd0,1)

Comment: And here is the sequence efi and in efi there are two foldera ubuntu/ and boot/ , under ubuntu there are some files which are grubx64.efi, grub.cfg, shimx64.efi, mmx64.efi, bootx64.csv and under boot/ there are two files which are bootx64.efi. And fbx64.efi

Comment: So (hd0,1) is your EFI partition. We are looking for a grub.cfg file, but it's not the one in that partition. That file establishes the prefix and the configfile and it's wrong, that's why grub can't boot. Keep trying until you find the partition where Ubuntu is actually installed. You should see all typical Ubuntu files and folders: bin, boot, dev, etc, home... initrd.img, vmlinuz

Comment: In (hd0,4) there are folders like home, media boot etc but files like vmlinuz initrd.img are not available

Comment: All files and folders are: lost+found/ boot/ swapfile etc/ media/ bin dev/ home/ lib lib32 lib64 libx32 mnt/ opt/ proc/ root/ run/ sbin/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ sdcrom/

Comment: That's it! Now, using ls command, check that there is a grub.cfg file inside (hd0,4)/boot/grub/

Comment: Yes, thats available

Comment: Prefix is already set to (hd0,gpt4)/boot/grub and root = hd0,gpt4

Comment: One of the error is: attempt to read or write outside of disk 'hd0'  , you need to loaf kernel first

Comment: Did you do insmod normal? and then normal?

Comment: After having done "insmod normal" and then "normal". If it doesn't boot, do: "set root=(hd0,gpt4)" mind the brackets! Then you need "linux /path/to/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda4" and "initrd /path/to/initrd.img". After all that, just "boot"

Comment: There should be some vmlinuz-5.4.0-* and initrd.img-5.4.0-* inside (hd0,gpt4)/boot/. Choose one of them, but make sure both vmlinuz and initrd.img are the same version, and issue the commands in the comment just above.

Comment: If after doing this you still get the error "attempt to read or write outside of disk" then you might have some kind of file corruption and that's why grub cannot read the needed files and proceed. You'll have to perform some fsck like in this answer [https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125590/attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1125590/attempt-to-read-or-write-outside-of-disk-hd0-ubuntu)

Comment: Yeah, found those files, folders and files in /boot : vmlinuz grub/ efi/ vmlinuz.old vmlinuz-5.4.0-29-generic initrd.img init.imh-5.4.0.29-generic memtest86+.elf etc....

Comment: Accomplished :) Thanks

Comment: I'm glad things finally worked out for you!